# Yii2. Model::loadMultipe. How to load class fields too?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

How to load not only DB attributes, but fields too with `loadMultipe`?

I have such a model

```
class Person extends ActiveRecord
{

    public $birthdate_month;

    public $birthdate_day;

    public $birthdate_year;

...

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            [['birthdate_month', 'birthdate_day', 'birthdate_year'], 'integer'],
            [['birthdate_month', 'birthdate_day', 'birthdate_year'], 'required']
        ];
    }

// I store data as one DATA field in DB and than use such methods to show it to the user

    public function afterFind()
    {
        if (isset($this->birthdate)) {
            $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->birthdate); //just a data-manipulation library

            $this->birthdate_month = $date->month;
            $this->birthdate_day   = $date->day;
            $this->birthdate_year  = $date->year;
        }

        return parent::afterFind();
    }



    public function beforeValidate()
    {
        $date            = Carbon::create($this->birthdate_year, $this->birthdate_month, $this->birthdate_day); //just a data-manipulation library
        $this->birthdate = $date->toDateString();

        return parent::beforeValidate();
    }
}
```

And such a view

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>

<?php foreach ($children as $i => $child): ?> //there are multiple persons (children)

...

 <?=$form->field($child, '[]birthdate_month', [...])->dropDownList([
                    '1'  => 'January',
                    ...
                ])?>

...

<?php endforeach; ?>

...

<?=Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'ui primary button big'])?>
...

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

In controller

```
Person::loadMultiple($children, Yii::$app->request->post());
```

fills attributes, but fields are still null. I need them, cause I use it to concat and make one date field in the DB. How to load them too?

Comment: declare that field also in public

Comment: @vishva but it is public)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be added iterator to passing array in the view

```
 <?=$form->field($child, "[$i]birthdate_month", [...])->dropDownList([
                    '1'  => 'January',
                    ...
                ])?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use datepicker widget for put  your date birthday  that included day, month and year, this widget is calendar

Comment: I know, but my client insisted on such way of entering the data :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$formDetails = Yii::$app->request->post('Person', []);
foreach ($formDetails as $i => $value) 
{
  $model = new Person();
  $model->setAttributes($value);
  $models[] = $model;
}
```

Comment: That is exact, what internal function of Yii2 do.